# Understanding System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute with base classes

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlignore

I have two classes, shown below:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeDerived))]
public class SomeBase
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDerived : SomeBase
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public new string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize and instance of `SomeDerived` I don't expect to see a value for `SomeProperty`. However, I do. I've tried other approaches such as having `SomeProperty` declared as `virtual` in `SomeBase` and overriding it in `SomeDerived`. Still I see it in a serialized instance of `SomeDerived`.

Can anyone explain what is going on with the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`?

For completeness, my deserialization code is below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeDerived someDerived = new SomeDerived { SomeProperty = "foo" };

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeBase));

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memStream, Encoding.Default);
        ser.Serialize(memStream, someDerived);

        xmlWriter.Close();
        memStream.Close();
        string xml = Encoding.Default.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());

        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

### Edit

I get the same behaviour if I change the serializer declaration to `new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeDerived))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out.  It uses the override on the XmlSerializer constructor to pass in some serialization overrides:

```
SomeDerived someDerived = new SomeDerived { SomeProperty = "foo" };

// Create the XmlAttributeOverrides and XmlAttributes objects.
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

/* Use the XmlIgnore to instruct the XmlSerializer to ignore
    the GroupName instead. */
attrs = new XmlAttributes();
attrs.XmlIgnore = true;
overrides.Add(typeof(SomeBase), "SomeProperty", attrs);

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeBase), overrides);

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memStream, Encoding.Default);
ser.Serialize(memStream, someDerived);

xmlWriter.Close();
memStream.Close();
string xml = Encoding.Default.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: OK, that approach works for this specific scenario. However, is there a more generic approach that would also work?

Comment: @Richard Ev - I'm not sure why the `XmlIgnore` attribute isn't working out of the box.  I think its due to the fact that you hiding the property with `new`.  I also attempted the same by changing `SomeProperty` to virtual and overriding in the derived class.  It smells like a bug to me that the attributes aren't working for overridden members.